# Scroll to Top after filtering DIV elements?

Tags: javascript, html

In short, I have a filter installed on my site, its functionality is very similar/exactly the same to the one you see in the link. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_elements
You can "Show all" DIV elements, but you also can filter through them.

**Problem:** I want to make sure my page "Scrolls up" after the user clicks on any of the filters. Essentially showing the relevant filtered elements **only**.
Any suggested .JS scripts?

Here is a part of the HTML + respective  PHP of my filter?

```
                <a href="#" class="filter-btn" data-filter="opd-list-id-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>" style="background:<?php echo $filter_background_color ?>;color:<?php echo $filter_text_color ?> !important;">
            <?php echo esc_html($item->post_title); ?>
            <?php
            if($item_count == 'on'){
                echo '<span class="opd-item-count-fil">('.esc_html($item_count_disp).')</span>';
            }
            ?>
        </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the function scrollIntoView() on click event

```js
var elmnt = document.getElementById("test");
test.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Any help in embedding the  .JS you mentioned into the HTML snippet below:
 <a href="#" class="filter-btn" data-filter="opd-list-id-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>" style="background:<?php echo $filter_background_color ?>;color:<?php echo $filter_text_color ?> !important;">

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.scrollTo(x, y);
```

if you want to scroll to top of page, send in 0, 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can give the top div an id and then link to this id on the filters.

```
<div id="topbar"></div>
...
<a href="#topbar"></a>
```

this works in all browser and without javascript. But it will not **scroll** to the top, but **jump** to the top.
As enhancement you can attach an event listener on the filters and use [scrollIntoView](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

Answer (score 0):

```
in the click event listener block,add scrollTo(0,0);or  window.scrollTo(0,0);

e.g: 
const filterClick=filterVariable.addEventListener('click',e =>{

  e.preventDefault();//to prevent unnecessary refreshment
window.scrollTo(0,0);//This solves the problem
});
```